# iTunes UI artifacts

Tags: mac, itunes, user-interface, visual-artifacts

Two days ago I found out that iTunes interface become buggy. Here are some screenshots:

UI bugs in listview headers:

[image]

iTunes doesn't download app icons in App Store:

[image]

CoverFlow doesn't show album arts:

[image]

Finder and other apps are working well, without any artifacts. 
Macbook 062 (Intel C2D 2.13, GMA950), Mac OS X 10.6.2, iTunes 9.0.2.

I have reinstalled iTunes via Apple's site - nothing.

What do you advice to do?

Comment: Reinstalling 10.6.2 update didn't resolve issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Missing file: 
/System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeComponents.component/
Contents/Resources/ru.lproj/Localized.rsrc.

Copied it from en.lproj, artifacts disappeared.